# javaScript Beginner : simple function call

Tags: javascript

hi all im new here and also is beginner to learn javascript...
I have a problem now is calling function from the function start()
when I choose level and arithmetic operations it will start with function start() 
then the two variable will be save... 
but the problem is there cannot call to the next function level() and operation()
may I know what is the problem?
Is it I have error with >> if(levelselect=="1") and also if(operationselect=="add") for the selection that part...thanks for helping me

```js
<script language="javascript">
var levelselect;
var operationselect;
var num1;
var num2;
var data;
var result;
function start(myForm) {
    levelselect = myForm["level"].value;
    operationselect = myForm["operation"].value;
    level();
}
function level() {
    if (levelselect == "1") {
        num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1));
        num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1));
        operation();
    } else if (levelselect == "2") {
        num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10));
        num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10));
        operation();
    } else if (levelselect == "3") {
        num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 900 + 100));
        num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 900 + 100));
        operation();
    }
}
function operation() {
    if (operationselect == "add") {
        data = window.prompt(+num1 + " + " + num2 + "?", "0");
        result = parseInt(data);
        check();
    } else if (operationselect == "sub") {
        data = window.prompt(+num1 + " - " + num2 + "?", "0");
        result = parseInt(data);
        check();
    } else if (operationselect == "div") {
        data = window.prompt(+num1 + " / " + num2 + "?", "0");
        result = parseInt(data);
        check();
    } else if (operationselect == "mul") {
        data = window.prompt(+num1 + " * " + num2 + "?", "0");
        result = parseInt(data);
        check();
    }
}
 

</script>

<
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="start(this);return false;">
        <table align="center">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    <label>Choose your Level :</label>
                    <select id="level">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <td>
                    <label>Choose your arithmetic operations :</label>
                    <select id="operation">
                        <option value="add">Addition</option>
                        <option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
                        <option value="div">Division</option>
                        <option value="mul">Multiplication</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Generate question" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an '<' open at the end of the js.
And where is the check function?
Also yo need to correct the body tag: 
and where is your js included? in a file? or in the head?